# What's wrong here? Strange error message (for me)

Tags: c++, class

I try to set up an class in C++ but I get an error message. Does somebody has any idea?

```
class ClassX
{
public:
    ClassX** _owner;
    QVector<ClassX*> objects;

    ClassX( size_t start, size_t length, QString type = "" ) {
        _owner = nullptr;
    }


    ClassX(ClassX** owner) {
        _owner = owner;
    }

    ClassX(int i, ClassX** owner) {
        _owner = owner;
    }

    // working
    void add(){
        objects.append( new ClassX (*this));
    }

    // not working: error: no matching function for call to ‘ClassX::ClassX(int, ClassX&)’
    void add2(){
        objects.append( new ClassX (3, *this));
    }    
};
```

I don't know what to say. I think I have reduced the code to a minimum that is necessary for understanding.

Comment: Do you have a `ClassX` constructor taking one `int` argument and one `ClassX` argument? What are you trying to do with that? What is the purpose of `new ClassX (3, (*this))`?

Comment: By the way, when creating a [mcve], please copy-paste it into the question. Rewriting it could add other unrelated errors (like missing parentheses).

Comment: What IDE are you using?  because you missed a closing brace on that last `append`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think 'ClassX(int i, ClassX** owner)' should be a constructor for 'new ClassX (3, *this)'. These are hierarchically arranged instances and I want to know the position of the superior instance.

Comment: @jiveturkey You are right, but error still exists. ( I am using VSC with GCC on Ubuntu )

Comment: `*this` is of `ClassX` type. You probably want to change `ClassX**` to a reference type `ClassX&`

Comment: When asking a question about a compiler error, *always* include the actual text of the error in your question (*verbatim*) along with information about *what compiler* you are using and *what version of that compiler* as well as your exact compiler options. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call this constructor: `ClassX(int i, ClassX** owner)`, but when you call it with `objects.append(new ClassX (3, (*this))`, you're not giving the correct type to use that constructor.

When you use `*this` (a special pointer to the object currently being used), you're dereferencing it, which produces an instance of `ClassX&`- a reference to a `ClassX` object. This isn't the same thing as the dual pointer you specified in the second constructor, so the compiler expects to find a different constructor with the following declaration `ClassX::ClassX(int, ClassX&)`.

You can simply change the constructor to this: `ClassX(int i, ClassX &owner)`.

Comment: Thank you, but why does the first one works but not the second one?

Comment: `add2` tries to create a `ClassX` object by using the arguments `3` (an `int`), and `*this` (type `ClassX&`). When you call `new ClassX(3, *this)`, the compiler tries to look for a constructor that looks like this: `ClassX(int i, ClassX &owner)`, but because there isn't a constructor written like that, it doesn't compile. Essentially, `ClassX **owner`, and `ClassX &owner` are different types, so the constructor written as `ClassX(int i, ClassX** owner)` can't be used, which is why `add2` doesn't work- the constructor inside it doesn't match any constructors declared.